# OSError: TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML does not appear to have a file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt or flax_model.msgpack

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers, llama

I want to build myself an AI bot.
("TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML",model_type="llama", model_file="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin") I chose this model.

But I couldn't get it to work. I installed everything in requirements.txt but there is a problem somewhere. It is not solved.
My code app.py:

```
import streamlit_chat as st
from streamlit_chat import message
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader, DirectoryLoader
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory 

from transformers import AutoConfig, AutoModelForCausalLM 
 
# from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download

# # https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/v0.16.3/en/package_reference/file_download#huggingface_hub.hf_hub_download
# hf_hub_download(
#     repo_id="TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML",
#     filename="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",
#     local_dir="./models"
# )
#load the pdf files from the path
loader = DirectoryLoader('data/',glob="*.pdf",loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
documents = loader.load()

#split text into chunks
text_splitter  = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=500,chunk_overlap=50)
text_chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

#create embeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
                                   model_kwargs={'device':"cpu"})

#vectorstore
vector_store = FAISS.from_documents(text_chunks,embeddings)

# custom_prompt_template=""" Contextt: {} Question :{question} Helpful answer:"""


#
# def set_custom_prompt():
#     prompt = PromptTemplate(template=custom_prompt_template,input_variables=['context','question'])
#     return prompt

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML",model_type="llama", model_file="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin")
config.max_new_tokens = 512
config.temperature = 0.5
config.wbits=4
config.groupsize=128
llm = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML", model_file="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin", config=config) 

# llm = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML", model_file="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",config={'max_new_tokens':512,'temperature':0.5})

#create llm                
# llm = CTransformers(model="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin",model_type="llama", #llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin
                    # config={'max_new_tokens':512,'temperature':0.5})
                    # config={'max_new_tokens':128,'temperature':0.01})

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm,chain_type='stuff',
                                              retriever=vector_store.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k":2}),return_source_documents = True,
                                             #chain_type_kwargs={'prompt':prompt},
                                              memory=memory)

st.title("HealthCare ChatBot ‍⚕️")
def conversation_chat(query):
    result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": st.session_state['history']})
    st.session_state['history'].append((query, result["answer"]))
    return result["answer"]

def initialize_session_state():
    if 'history' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['history'] = []

    if 'generated' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['generated'] = ["Hello! Ask me anything about "]

    if 'past' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['past'] = ["Hey! "]

def display_chat_history():
    reply_container = st.container()
    container = st.container()

    with container:
        with st.form(key='my_form', clear_on_submit=True):
            user_input = st.text_input("Question:", placeholder="Ask about your Mental Health", key='input')
            submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Send')

        if submit_button and user_input:
            output = conversation_chat(user_input)

            st.session_state['past'].append(user_input)
            st.session_state['generated'].append(output)

    if st.session_state['generated']:
        with reply_container:
            for i in range(len(st.session_state['generated'])):
                message(st.session_state["past"][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + '_user', avatar_style="thumbs")
                message(st.session_state["generated"][i], key=str(i), avatar_style="fun-emoji")

# Initialize session state
initialize_session_state()
# Display chat history
display_chat_history()
```

Errors:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Calismalarim\ai\LLama2HealthCareChatBot-master> & c:/Users/myuser/Documents/Calismalarim/ai/LLama2HealthCareChatBot-master/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/myuser/Documents/Calismalarim/ai/LLama2HealthCareChatBot-master/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\myuser\Documents\Calismalarim\ai\LLama2HealthCareChatBot-master\app.py", line 49, in <module>
    llm = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML", model_file="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin", config=config)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Calismalarim\ai\LLama2HealthCareChatBot-master\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 566, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
  File "C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Calismalarim\ai\LLama2HealthCareChatBot-master\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 3321, in from_pretrained
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML does not appear to have a file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt or flax_model.msgpack.
```

how to resolve it?

i installed all pip requirements.txt

Comment: Did you check if one of those files exists and if not put it there in the path it says it wants it at?

Comment: Yes, I added that bin file to the project. but I don't understand the error